# Use of articles, which one is correct?

Tags: articles

Corinth was a rich, but not **a** very enlightened state

**OR**

Corinth was a rich, but not very enlightened state.

Which one should I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use either. It's a matter of style or preference.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, including another indefinite article *is* altogether a *matter of your personal style*. 
You can repeat the article if you want to emphasize, for example, the individual parts of a list.